# Address of Former Employers on Resume

Tags: resume, location

I now have 6 previous employers on my CV. A few (2) of them have evidently moved offices since I have left.

Is it good practice to:

1. Leave the addresses as they were when you left.
2. Update the addresses whenever you update your resume.
3. Do something else.

Comment: Heck, that's nothing.  Three of mine have *gone out of business* since I worked there.  (Hopefully just a coincidence?)

Comment: @Kyralessa happens all the time, all around the world... ;-) Even mighty banks sunk, General Motors almost became history in recent years ;-)

Comment: @Kyralessa It's not coincidence. It's a fine testament to how crucial you were to their business, and how foolish they were not to retain you!

Comment: @NWS - You might think to scrap a few of those references.  You really should only list the last 2-3 employeers or enough to give a picture of your last ten years of employement.  If you need more then 3 just give the company names and only provide the 1 or 2 references you WANT somebody to contact.

Comment: @Ramhound - These are employers I am listing, not references / referees.

Comment: @NWS - You don't have to list your entire work history on your resume only your recent work history.  Its for the same reason you don't list work history that is relevant to the position your applying for( i.e. summer job at a retail store ) when applying for a full-time position at Microsoft.   They don't care you can take Milk off the truck fast.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As others say - don't get into specifics, if your concern is street and number, skip it - keep it to the city.  If your concern is that they were in a certain city or town and have since moved - I recommend keeping the location you worked in.

Resume items are most useful as a way to reference your job history - the majority of readers of your resume are looking to get a sense of you and your job history.  Keeping the location you actually worked at, lets the reader:

- Scan his memory for anything he knows about that company and it's location - the business, the people working in it, anything about its reputation.  Even in a city, the people in a given industry often know quite a bit about other employers of a similar skill set.
- Shows your pattern of work - if you change the city each time the employer moves, you run the risk of giving the impression that you yourself have moved.  What that means to the reader is anyone's guess - my only point is that it isn't accurate, and you don't want to try to explain that in an interview.
- Assume consistency - after all, you're not going to remove a company when it goes out of business - so keep a consistent pattern.  Also, this will keep you from having to launch an update every time there's a move.

If a company wishes to do a reference check, they will likely send you a more detailed form asking for location and contact points. That's the time to get accurate information to share.  At that point, they will likely be calling and checking history, and so it helps to provide as much accuracy as possible in terms of finding the company.

In the meantime, you may encounter questions like "I didn't know that X company was in Y location..." - which are a great jumping off point for explanation.  For example "Well, when I worked there there was Y location, it was a great site.  I left when the business was waning, and eventually they had to disband Y location."

I've done similar, even when companies left my country entirely, and never had a problem with it.

Comment: I include the city largely because in big companies, it gives a point of reference.  A single Defense Contractor, in MA, for example, may have 3-10 campuses within a 2 hour drive of each other - they may be very different lines of business, and differently applicable, so knowing *where* the person was working can tell you quite a bit about what they were doing.  Mileage varies (pun intended). :)

Answer (score 26):

Scrap the addresses for good as it's only noise. I wouldn't even use a URL unless it points to some very fancy stuff related to your project. Even then, that probably belongs in a different section.

Answer (score 4):

The CV needs nothing more than the name of the company and the city. Most of the people that will read the resume don't need the address, because they will not be the one contacting the old employers. Publicizing a name, address and phone number on a resume that may end up being posted in place were thousands can see it would require getting permission from each contact.

That electronic submission may live for years and the contact information will become stale.

For many midsized and large companies the reference check will not go to your old manager but to a central location that will only confirm the dates of employment and job title.

Answer (score 2):

It is better not to mention the address in your CV. You should on only mention your employers names. If you like you can put the website in instead of the address. In my opinion it's better to use a website address.

Comment: Hi Jani, can you explain *why* it's better to use a website address? On the Workplace, we're looking for answers that *teach* others via explanations backed by facts, references, or specific experiences that happened to you personally. Here's the [edit] link. Good luck! :)